# Sending email via Amazon SES from php command line

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-10.04, amazon-ses

I've been using a php wrapper from http://www.orderingdisorder.com/aws/ses/ to send emails via Amazon SES successfully for several months. I now need to automate some emails from batch jobs and have created php scripts to be ran from the command line, executed by crontab.

The problem I'm having is that although the scripts run fine, and the tasks within them complete without issues, and although the ses part is returning a messageid and requestid, I do not receive the emails.

I've checked for environmental differences between the php web config and command-line config but can't see anything obvious. Anyone experienced this issue or got any pointers for where I can look into next? Cheers.

EDIT: Got it: SES doesn't seem to like the from and to addresses being the same anymore

Answer (score 0):

Have look at these links:

http://www.millcreeksys.com/get-up-and-running-quickly-with-amazon-ses-on-your-php-website/
http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/Amazon-SES/8945574369528337

This involves replacing the sendmail handler to custom SES-script.

Cheers.